# Extending $\{u_1, u_2\}$ to an orthonormal basis when finding an SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, svd

I've been working through my linear algebra textbook, and when finding an SVD there's just one thing I don't understand.

For example, finding an SVD for the 3x2 matrix [A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDImZ.png). I will skip the steps of finding the eigenvectors, eigenvalues, singular values... anyway, we find that

$$
V = \begin{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1 & \vec{v}_2\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2\\
1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and we know that

$$
\vec{u}_n = \frac{1}{\sigma_n}A\vec{v}_n
$$

which gives

$$
\vec{u}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}2/\sqrt6\\1/\sqrt6\\1/\sqrt6\end{bmatrix}, \vec{u}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\-1/\sqrt2\\1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}
$$

but we know that $U$ is a $m$ by $m$ matrix, so it must be 3 by 3, and so we have to find $\vec{u}_3$. This is where I get stuck; the book says that one method to do this is to use the Gram-Schmidt Process, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this with the vectors shown above.

Comment: Choose a vector $x$ linearly independent of $u_1,u_2$ basically at random; one possible choice is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then run Gram-Schmidt on $\{ u_1,u_2,x \}$.

Comment: You can also view the extra left singular vectors as a basis for the null space of $A^T$ if that helps

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to approach this problem.

**Eyeball method**

Scrape off the distractions of normalization. The column vectors are
$$
 \tilde{v}_{1} = 
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  2 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{array} \right], \qquad
%
 \tilde{v}_{2} = 
%
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
  0 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{array} \right].
%
$$
Find a vector perpendicular to both. One such solution is
$$
 \tilde{v}_{3} = 
%
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{array} \right].
$$

**Systematic approach**

Start with
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 2 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$
Find the nullspace $\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}^{*} \right)$. The row reduced form is
$$
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{A}^{T} &\mapsto \mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{A}^{T}} \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{crc}
 2 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
 &\mapsto 
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccr}
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
$$
In terms of basic variables,
$$
\begin{align}
 x_{1} &= -x_{3}, \\
 x_{2} &=  x_{3}.
\end{align}
$$
Making the natural choice that $x_{3}=1$ produces the column vector
$$
%
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  x_{1} \\
  x_{2}  \\
  x_{3} 
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\
  1 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Gram-Schmidt**

Make any choice for the third vector and use the process of Gram and Schmidt to make it an orthogonal vector. A wise choice to begin is
$$
 \tilde{v}_{3} =
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]
$$
Why is this a wise choice? It is rich in $0$s, which make manipulation easy.

Define the operator which projects the vector $u$ onto the vector $v$ as
$$
 p_{u\to v} = 
\frac{v\cdot u}{u \cdot u}
u
$$
The Gram-Schmidt process fixes $v_{3}$ using the prescription
$$
 v_{GS} = v_{3} - 
\frac{v_{3} \cdot v_{1}} {v_{1} \cdot v_{1}} v_{1} -
\frac{v_{3} \cdot v_{2}} {v_{2} \cdot v_{2}} v_{2}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{3}
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]
%
=
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{array} \right] 
%
-
%
\frac{1}{6}
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]
%
-
%
\frac{1}{2}
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
 0 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]
%
$$

The normalized form is the column vector you want
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\left[ \begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]
$$